# VB6 SET statement - is it supposed to actually execute code inside an external DLL?

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 Exe and a V6 DLL both of which generally work Ok however with a new adaptation of the DLL it is causing me problems as the DLL internal code is actually executing - which is messing up my app - but I am not sure if this is actually correct behaviour.

The VB6 Exe section of code is as follows ;

```
Set Scanner = New Devices.Scanner

  If Scanner.SupportedDevicesCount > 0 Then
  Dim i As Long

  For i = 1 To Scanner.SupportedDevicesCount
      With Scanner.SupportedDevicesInfo(i)
          If .Available = True Then
  ..
  ..
```

In the external DLL there is the following code ;

```
Public Property Get SupportedDevicesInfo(ByVal Index As Long) As DeviceInfo
  On Error Resume Next
  SupportedDevicesInfo = mSupportedDevices(Index).DeviceInfo
End Property
```

My issue is that this SupportedDevicesInfo is executing "twice" and I cannot understand why.

It executes Once at the  `Set Scanner = New Devices.Scanner`  and then again at the  `Scanner.SupportedDevicesInfo(i)`

This results in various internal functions taking place at the device namely

```
Private Function IScanDevice_OpenDevice() As Scan_ResultCodes
```

which should not happen until called.

Would appreciate some help on this. 
thanks

Comment: Is there anything in the Class_Initialize of the VB6 DLL?

Comment: If you think this has something to do with the code being in a DLL, as a test add all the DLL code to the EXE project and see if anything changes. For that matter, don't compile to a separate DLL in the first place if you can avoid it.

Comment: As @OldBoyCoder implies, if there are no UI elements in the DLL, the only code that should execute is in the Class_Initialize procedure. Check there to be sure you're not invoking the Info code, even indirectly.

Comment: Well, any Sub Main code executes each time a new client links as well as far as I can recall.

Comment: @Bob77 I think you're right but it's been a long time and I've lost the MSDN discs that had my copy of VB6 on so I can't check!.

Comment: You can debug by adding the dll project to the solution. then reference it in the exe project. This way you can actually line by line debug your code

Comment: I agree with @TSion.D.P, except that it was called a Group and not a Solution in VB6.

Comment: Thank you all for those comments/suggestions they helped a lot. Class_Initialize had an amount of code and in there was a condition that ran the code I was not wanting to run. I didn't realize Class_Initialize was the culprit. Have also set up a test EXE to launch the DLL as a Group Thanks again.